# Undefined variable: invite in view

Tags: php, laravel

I am inviting my users based on a OneTime Url. I have declared my constructor as public in my InviteUser.php.

After i trigger to send the invite, the email fails to send and it returns an error `"Undefined variable: invite in my view`.  But as far as i have declared my constructor public, i am expecting the view to have `invite` as declared.

In any case, what am i missing out please?

**InviteUser.php**

```
public function __construct(Invite $invite)
    {
        $this->invite = $invite;
    }


    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('hello@gexample.com')->view('emails.invite');   
    }
```

**invite.blade.php**

```
<p>Hi,</p>

<p>Someone has invited you to access their account.</p>

<a href="{{ route('accept', $invite->token) }}">Click here</a> to activate!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send your $invite to the view:

```
public function __construct(Invite $invite)
{
    $this->invite = $invite;
}


public function build()
{
    return $this->from('hello@gexample.com')->view('emails.invite', ['invite' => $this->invite]);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna pass value into your view file you have to pass through controller while loading your view,
just like this

```
$banners = Banner::get();
return View('admin.banner.index', compact('banners'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the variable in the view to access that variable inside your view. So code should be like as follows:

```
public function build()
{
    $data = array(
         "invite" => $this->invite
    );
    return $this->from('hello@gexample.com')->view('emails.invite', $data);   
}
```